# How to configure pam_mkhomedir to create home directories with 0750 instead of 0777 permissions?

Tags: permissions, pam

We would like to change the default permissions of the home directories created by pam_mkhomedir. The permissions default to 0755, we would prefer 0750. Changing the permissions of /etc/skel did not do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `umask` parameter of `pam_mkhomedir` to 0027 was the solution.

From [`man pam_mkhomedir`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/pam_mkhomedir.8):

```
umask=mask
   The user file-creation mask is set to mask. The default value of
   mask is 0022.
```

Answer (score 0):

From: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man8/useradd.8.html

> ```
> The following configuration variables in /etc/login.defs change the behavior of this tool:
> [..]
> UMASK (number)
>
>     The file mode creation mask is initialized to this value. If not specified, the mask will be initialized to 022.
>
>     useradd and newusers use this mask to set the mode of the home directory they create
> ```

When creating a new user with useradd, the `/etc/skel` directory is used (and its permissions copied).

Edit `/etc/login.defs` and look for the `UMASK` setting - this is a umask that will be applied to the new user's newly created directory. The default is 022. If you want the permissions to be 750, then change UMASK to 027, then create new users with:

```
useradd --create-home <username>
```

Note that this will not work if you use `adduser` instead.
Note this does not affect permission when pam_mkhomedir creates profile.

Answer (score 0):

There are two places the folder permission for new users can be controlled from reading `man adduser`, `man useradd` and `man newuser`, these are:

1. `/etc/adduser.conf`:

   - In there the `DIR_MODE=0755` may be changed to `0750` to achieve what you want the `adduser` tool uses this configuration to determine directory permissions.
2. `/etc/useradd.conf`:

   - In there the the `UMASK=022` is used by `useradd` and the `newuser` tools to determine initial folder permissions.

So depending on which tool you intend to use, you will need to alter the configurations in either of these locations to get what you want.

See:

```
man useradd
man newuser
man adduser
```